# How to fix mutating table error in trigger?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I have two tables with the name of `item` and `stock_item`.
When I update the `item` table then trigger with the name `beforeItem` should fire, which subtracts new updated `qty` from `stock_qty`. But it throws

> ORA-04091: table **** is mutating trigger/function may not see it

How can I fix this?

My tables:

```
create table stock_item
(no number primary key,itemName varchar2(10),stock_Qty number);

create table item 
(no number,Name varchar2(10),qty number);
```

My trigger:

```
create or replace trigger beforeItem
before update on item
for each row 
declare 
chk_no number;
chk_item varchar2(10);
chk_qty number;
--pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
-- this code will skip the update code.
begin
select no,name,qty into chk_no, chk_item,chk_qty from item where  no=:new.no 
and name=:new.name;
update stock_item set itemName = itemName - chk_qty where no=chk_no and 
itemName=chk_item; 
--commit;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. it is not clear what you are asking. Please rephrase your question and tell us what you are trying to do, what error you are experiencing, and how we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference table ITEM in this trigger because it causes your error. Instead of using SELECT statement use new/old parameters. Try this version of the trigger.

```
create or replace trigger beforeItem
  before update on item
  for each row 
begin
  -- if :new.qty is not null then
    update stock_item set 
      -- logic to maintaint if no changes on qty field were done
      stock_Qty = stock_Qty - ( nvl(:new.qty,0) - nvl(:old.qty,0) ) 
      where no=:new.no and itemName=:new.name; 
  -- end if;
end;
```

Comment: I subtract the stock_qty only if I know the current value of item_qty from the item table.

Comment: In the update trigger, you have access to the old and new value of each field, so you know it. I understood that you want to implement logic to maintain a quantity of the stock via the trigger, but I don't think that triggers is the best place to implement such an operation.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle hurls ORA-04091 when a trigger issues DML against the table which owns the trigger; this includes SELECT statements. The reason is simple: the state of the table is unknown because the trigger is firing **during a transaction**, so the outcome of the trigger's DML is unpredictable.

The solution is usually quite simple: remove the DML. That certainly would seem to be the answer here, because your :NEW record has all the values you need to execute the update on `stock_item`:

```
create or replace trigger beforeItem
    before update on item
    for each row 
 begin

    update stock_item si
    set si.stock_Qty = si.stock_Qty - :new.qty 
    where si.no = :new.no; 

end;
```

> but the stock_item table don't know what is the current value of the item table qty to subtract from.

Okay, so what you mean is, you want to update the STOCK_ITEM.QTY with the *difference* between the old (current) ITEM.QTY and the new (updated) value. Then that would be something like:

```
create or replace trigger beforeItem
    before update on item
    for each row 
 begin

    update stock_item si
    set si.stock_Qty = si.stock_Qty - ( (nvl(:old.qty,0) - nvl(:new.qty,0)) )
    where si.no = :new.no; 

end;
```

Here is a demo of my solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c8c4/1).

---

Incidentally, note that I have corrected your UPDATE statement: subtracting Item Quantity from the Stock Name really doesn't make sense. Also, there is no need to use `itemName` in the WHERE clause when there is a primary key to use.

Comment: I subtract the stock_qty only if I know the current value of item_qty from the item table.

Comment: off curse I know but the stock_item table don't know what is the current value of the item table qty to subtract from.

Comment: ORA-04091: table **** is mutating trigger/function may not see it

Comment: Thanks for being there when I needed you.

Comment: You are of course at liberty to choose which answer you think is best but I would be interested to know why you changed your mind